# Quarkus RestClient unable to mock method with multiple @Consumes content-types

Tags: junit, mocking, quarkus

I'm currently trying to mock a Quarkus  @RestClient which is generated from an OpenApi spec. This RestClient contains the following method:

```
@PATCH
@Path("/{id}/")
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
@GeneratedMethod ("destinations_partial_update")
public DestinationPatch destinationsPartialUpdate(
    @GeneratedParam("id") @PathParam("id") Integer id, 
    PatchedDestinationPatchRequest patchedDestinationPatchRequest
);
```

When running my test class, this gives a problem on the Mock. I setup the test class as follows:

```
@QuarkusTest
class DestinationServiceTest {

    @Inject
    DestinationService service;

    @InjectMock
@RestClient
DestinationsApi apiMock;

.....

}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Failed to generate client for class interface nl.belastingdienst.pvb.dinq.generated.client.api.DestinationsApi : Multiple `@Consumes` values used in a MicroProfile Rest Client
```

It seems the @RestClient mocking setup cannot handle a method with more then one @Consumes value, but my OpenApi spec forces this on me. Is there a way around this seeing how I have no control over the OpenApi spec file? I do not want to alter it before generating my Quarkus Rest client because this will cause a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: On the client side only one MediaType is allowed. See https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client/issues/110

Comment: Ok, that clarifies that then. Now to figure out how to tell the generator to only add one MediaType instead of all MediaTypes defined in the spec...

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it. Turns out there are two variants of the RestEasy client library, classic and reactive. I was using reactive, which annot handle multiple \@Consumes media types. I have now switched to RestEasy classic. This variant CAN handle multiple \@Consume media types. See the following for more info: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/blob/2.2.12/README.md#resteasy-reactive-and-classic-support